# How to add <Link> react-router to Material-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using the material-table library is a Datatable based on Material-UI Table.

The datatable has the properties of editable and add a new record in the same table but I don't want to do it in the same table.

I need use a button because I want it to open a material UI menu. However, I don't know how I can add a link or something similar.

I tried it with the following code snippet but it tells me that Link is not defined even though it does matter

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import  axios  from 'axios';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function TableProducts() {

const url='/api/products';

const [product, setProduct]= useState({Products:[]});


 useEffect(()=>{
    const getProduct=async()=>{
            const response =await axios.get(url);
            setProduct(response.data);
    }
    getProduct();
},[]);

  return (

<MaterialTable
      title="Products"
      columns={[
        {title: 'id',field: 'id', type: 'numeric', hidden:'false'},
        { title: 'nameproduct',field: 'nameproduct', },
        { title: 'description', field: 'description' },
        { title: 'price', field: 'price' },
      ]} 
      data={product.Products}
      options={{
        filtering: true,
        sorting: true
      }}
      actions={[
        {
          icon: 'edit',
          tooltip: 'Edit ',
          onClick: () => 
            <Link to={`/product/${data._id}/edit`}>Edit</Link> 

        }
      ]}
      />

    );
  }
```

I want to get something like this done

```
                <Link
                    to={`/product/edit/${product.id}`}
                    className="btn btn-success mr-2">Editar
                </Link>
```

Comment: Your code is a bit lacking. It's hard to tell if you want to create a new link on each table row, or what.

Comment: Have you made sure to import Link?

Comment: @Rob yes i do the import, import {NavLink, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you nest it within a Router component like

```
<Router>
<MaterialTable ...>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
   </MaterialTable>
  </Router>
```

Added the part about incorporating Material Table. Just try to make the Router the root container.

Comment: but if I am using a table

Answer (score 0):

```
actions={[
    icon: () => <Link to='/test'><Icon /></Link>,
    tooltip: 'tip',
    onClick: (event, rowData) => 
        localStorage.setItem('selectedRowData', rowData)
    ]}
```

> Link to='/test' -->  The desired root that you want to open by clicking on the action
>
> Icon --> Action icon that you can use with import and placement
>
> onClick -->
> In the Onclick event, you save the information you want to take to the desired root

tip:Keep in mind that if the data is large, it is better to use redux

Comment: Could you provide some explanation to your answer?

Comment: use localStorage or Redux to transfer data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
actions={[
        {
          icon: 'edit',
          tooltip: 'Edit ',
          onClick: () => 
            <Link to={`/product/${data._id}/edit`}>Edit</Link> 

        }
      ]}
```

Do this

```
actions={[
    rowData => ({
      icon: () => <Link to={`/product/${rowData._id}/edit`}>Edit(Replace with icon code)</Link>
      tooltip: 'Edit ',
      onClick: (rowData)
    })
  ]}
```

For more information visit https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions